# How to handle abstraction and specialization of a class and its attributes?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, polymorphism, abstract-class, abstraction

Apologies for this quite *abstract* title.

More clearly:

- I have two classes `Controler` and `Interface` (hardware sense, unrelated to design pattern)
- Both are abstract with some pure virtual methods and hence intended to be subclassed
- I need each `Controler` created to be associated with an `Interface` object
- Each `Controler` subclass only work with a subset of `Interface` subclasses (`ControlerA + InterfaceA` or `ControlerB + InterfaceB` but not `ControlerA + InterfaceB`)
- Each `Interface` subclass has its own methods not inherited (this is why only one kind of `Controler` can use it)
- The `Controler` base class need to call some method of the base class `Interface`

I try to pass an `Interface` objet to the `Controler` constructor, hence in my class definition the `Interface` attribute represents the abstract base class. But if my `Controler` subclass A need to call a specific method of the `Interface` A, an compilation error is raised as the `Interface` base class doesn't own this method.

The only workaround I found was to call `dynamic_cast`, but it obviously seems wrong.

---

Here are my `Interface` classes:

```
class Interface {
public:
  Interface() {};
  virtual void method() = 0;
};

class InterfaceA : public Interface {
public:
  InterfaceA() : Interface() {};
  void method() override { cout << "A overriding" << endl; }
  void onlyA() { cout << "A only" << endl; }
};

class InterfaceB : public Interface {
public:
  InterfaceB() : Interface() {};
  void method() override { cout << "B overriding" << endl; }
  void onlyB() { cout << "B only" << endl; }
};
```

Here are my `Controler` classes:

```
class Controler {
public:
  Controler(Interface* i) : m_interface(i) {};
  virtual void uniqueMethod() = 0;
  void commonMethod() { m_interface->method(); }
  Interface* m_interface;
};

class ControlerA : public Controler {
public:
  ControlerA(InterfaceA* i) : Controler(i) {};
  void uniqueMethod() override {dynamic_cast<InterfaceA *>(m_interface)->onlyA();}
};

class ControlerB : public Controler {
public:
  ControlerB(InterfaceB* i) : Controler(i) {};
  void uniqueMethod() override {dynamic_cast<InterfaceB *>(m_interface)->onlyB();}
};
```

And here is how I plan to use them:

```
auto ia = new InterfaceA();
auto ca = ControlerA(ia);
ca.commonMethod();  // Method defined in the base class
ca.uniqueMethod();  // Method defined in InterfaceA only
```

You can try it on [Repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/LumpyWeepyKeygen).

Is there any design pattern to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a problem indeed. There exists an invariant between the dynamic type of `m_interface` and the dynamic type of the object that implement `Controler`. But this invariant cannot be maintained by the `Controler` class. So the `m_interface` member is not a the right place.

The consequence is that you need to check at runtime that this member has the right type by using the `dynamic_cast` each time you call `uniqueMethod`. If the invariant is broken, the code will have UB because it would dereference a null pointer.

So this is not really a design pattern issue, but more fundamentally an object oriented programming recommendation: *classes must ensure invariants.*

```
class Controler {
public:
  virtual void uniqueMethod() = 0;
  virtual void commonMethod() = 0;
};

class ControlerA : public Controler {
public:
  ControlerA(InterfaceA* i):m_interface{i} {
    assert(dynamic_cast<InterfaceA*>(i)!=nullptr);
    };
  void uniqueMethod() override { m_interface->onlyA();}
  void commonMethod() override { m_interface->method(); }
private: InterfaceA* m_interface;
};

class ControlerB : public Controler {
public:
  ControlerB(InterfaceB* i):m_interface{i} {
    assert(dynamic_cast<InterfaceB*>(i)!=nullptr);
    };
  void uniqueMethod() override { m_interface->onlyB();}
  void commonMethod() override { m_interface->method(); }
private: InterfaceB* m_interface;
};
```

So now, it looks that we have a regular pattern, so this is where we can think about a more generic design:

```
template<class Inter,void(Inter::* OnlyFunc)()>
class ControlerImpl : public Controler {
public:
  ControlerImpl(Inter* i):m_interface{i} {
    assert(dynamic_cast<Inter*>(i)!=nullptr);
    };
  void uniqueMethod() override { (m_interface->*OnlyFunc)();}
  void commonMethod() override { m_interface->method(); }
  private: Inter* m_interface;
};
using ControlerA = ControlerImpl<InterfaceA,&InterfaceA::onlyA>;
using ControlerB = ControlerImpl<InterfaceB,&InterfaceB::onlyB>;
```

Comment: I was thinking of using `template` to solve my issue, glad to see that this is what you suggest. Actually, you made me realize that my whole conception of using pointers to define abstract classes as classes member is probably wrong and that I should always have used templates instead.